# Loading D3 with Nuxt/Vue

Tags: d3.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to implement D3 in an app I am building with Nuxt.  I have successfully imported it into a view in the `<script>` section with `import * as d3 from 'd3'` however because the app is being rendered server-side D3's functionality doesn't work (i.e. `d3.select(...)`) due to the lack of browser.  In the [Nuxt plugin documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#client-side-only) it suggests a pattern for client-only external plugins:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    { src: '~plugins/vue-notifications', ssr: false }
  ]
}
```

I attempted to implement the pattern in the `nuxt.config.js` of my project:

```
module.exports = {
  head: {
    title: 'My Demo App',
    meta: [...],
    link: [...]
  },

  loading: {...},

  plugins: [
     { src: '~node_modules/d3/build/d3.js', ssr: false}
  ]
}
```

However D3 throws a `ReferenceError` while looking for `document` and Nuxt throws a `SyntaxError` in the console pointing to something in the plugins field of `nuxt.config.js`.

For reference, `demo.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="demo-container"></div>
</template>

<script>
  import * as d3 from 'd3';
  d3.select('.demo-container');
</script>
```

Would someone be able to point to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should accept an answer if it solved your problem. Otherwise, the question remains in the queue as unresolved.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone coming to this page looking for a solution,
these suggestions from piyushchauhan2011 [here on GitHub](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/771) sent me in the right direction.

All I needed to do:

- import d3 in my single-file component, and then
- do any DOM manipulation with d3 only within `mounted()`

Before all this, I had to of course add d3 to my project with `yarn add d3` (or `npm install d3`).

[Edit: removed link that no longer works. It wasn't that relevant anyway.]

Comment: @jl0w any way you keep records of the code from the answer? Links from github are no longer valid

Comment: @delux There's no code. I was talking about [this comment](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/771#issuecomment-305628601) on Github.

Comment: @jlow the links from that comment are not valid, therefore, the comment is no much helpful

Answer (score 5):

I was getting an error:

> Must use import to load ES Module: .../node_modules/d3/src/index.js require() of ES modules is not supported. require() of .../node_modules/d3/src/index.js from .../node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules. Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from .../node_modules/d3/package.json.

I solved it by reading this: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9223

which indicates you can add this to your `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
  build: {
    standalone: true,
  }
```

This allowed the d3 import to work.

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple step-by-step tutorial:

1. Create a new NuxtJS project (Skip this step if you have an existing project)

   ```sh
   npm init nuxt-app nuxtjs-d3js-example
   ```
2. Install D3JS

   ```sh
   npm install d3
   npm install @types/d3 --save-dev
   ```
3. Import D3JS and add a target

   HTML:

   ```html
   <p id="d3-target"></p>
   ```

   JavaScript:

   ```js
   import * as d3 from 'd3'
   export default {
     name: 'NuxtTutorial',
     mounted: function() {
       d3.select("#d3-target").text("This text is manipulated by d3.js")
     },
   }
   ```
4. Fix ES Module error (mentioned by @agm1984)

   Error:

   ```
   require() of ES Module /home/johnson/projects/nuxtjs-d3js-example/nuxtjs-d3js-example/node_modules/d3/src/index.js from /home/johnson/projects/nuxtjs-d3js-example/nuxtjs-d3js-example/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js not supported. Instead change the require of index.js in /home/johnson/projects/nuxtjs-d3js-example/nuxtjs-d3js-example/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
   ```

   `nuxt.config.js`:

   ```js
   build: {
     standalone: true,
   }
   ```

A minimal project example can be found at: https://github.com/j3soon/nuxtjs-d3js-example, with each step detailed in the [Git commit history](https://github.com/j3soon/nuxtjs-d3js-example/commits/master).