# How to load a resource on the client side only in Nuxt.js

Tags: d3.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to build an app using Tone.js on top of Nuxt.js. Tone.js requires the browser's Web Audio API and as Nuxt renders stuff on the server side my build keeps failing.

Nuxt addresses this in the [plugin documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#client-side-only) and I've followed that approach in my `nuxt.config.js` file writing:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [{src: '~node_modules/tone/build/Tone.js', ssr: false }],
}
```

however that results in this error: `[nuxt] Error while initializing app TypeError: Cannot read property 'isUndef' of undefined`. Looking at Tone's source I'm pretty sure this is because I'm getting it because the code is still being executed on the server side.

I've seen solutions putting the js file into the `static` folder and checking `process.browser` but both result in `Tone` being undefined.

My question seems to be the [same as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121264/loading-d3-with-nuxt-vue) if it's helpful additional context

Answer (score 11):

Instead of import a plugin, in your page.vue you can init *Tone.js* in the `mounted()` method, because this function is run only from client-side.

Example of `page/test.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    Tone.js
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      var Tone = require("Tone");
      var synth = new Tone.Synth().toMaster();
      synth.triggerAttackRelease("C4", "8n");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to do the same with nuxt bridge and pdfviewer from `pdfjs-dist` version `2.14.305` and it's working in local. When building for production and trying it, i get a `navigator is not defined`. Any idea please?