# How to import extrenal library on mounted hook in Nuxt Js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I use [conversation form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/conversational-form) package in my nuxt js project. I found custom [component from github](https://github.com/space10-community/conversational-form/issues/303) where used this package.

**Component code:**

```
<template>
  <form id="my-form-element" cf-form></form>
</template>

<script>
import * as cf from 'conversational-form'

export default {
  mounted: function() {
    this.setupForm()
  },
  methods: {
    setupForm: function() {
      const formFields = [
        {
          tag: 'input',
          type: 'text',
          name: 'firstname',
          'cf-questions': 'What is your firstname?'
        },
        {
          tag: 'input',
          type: 'text',
          name: 'lastname',
          'cf-questions': 'What is your lastname?'
        }
      ]

      this.cf = cf.startTheConversation({
        options: {
          submitCallback: this.submitCallback
        },
        tags: formFields
      })
      this.$el.appendChild(this.cf.formEl)
    },
    submitCallback: function() {
      const formDataSerialized = this.cf.getFormData(true)
      console.log('Formdata, obj:', formDataSerialized)
      this.cf.addRobotChatResponse(
        'You are done. Check the dev console for form data output.'
      )
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Now when I use this component get error message:

> window is not defined

As solution of this error recomended this [answer from stackowerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890018/how-to-load-a-resource-on-the-client-side-only-in-nuxt-js)

And after seen this answer I've change component code.

**Changes:**

1.Removed`import * as cf from 'conversational-form'`

2.Replaced `mounted()` hook content to:

```
var cf = require('conversational-form')
this.setupForm()
```

After changes error fixed but package not work correctly. When call this library inside methods as `this.cf` nuxt js can't found `cf` var. How I can fix this problem?

Also you can see live demo of this package in `vue js` [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-conversational-form-example)

Answer (score 0):

This is a rare situation that you may need to use the `<client-only>` tag.  If you're using a version older than 2.9.0, then it is `<no-ssr>`.  Docs found [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-client-only).

Example:

```
<template>
  <client-only>
    <form id="my-form-element" cf-form></form>
  </client-only>
</template>
<script>
import * as cf from 'conversational-form'

export default { ... }
</script>
```

This instructs Nuxt to only render the component client side, where window is defined.